# Reliablely map network drive on Windows machine remotely from Linux machine

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, samba, network-share

**Background**

Fairly new to networking. I have two machines. One is a Linux machine running Debian (`Computer A`), the other is a Windows machine (`Computer B`). On the Linux machine is a Samba share and both machines are on the same network. I can log into `Computer B` via an SSH session from `Computer A` using key pair authentication. I can also access the Samba share from `Computer B` directly or by mapping it to a drive letter in Windows.

I want to run a PowerShell script that resides on `Computer B` via an SSH session from `Computer A`. The script will happily run and executes commands to mount the Samba share on `Computer B` as a `PSDrive`. `Computer B` will be reverted to a "base" snapshot every time before this script is run (So the drive is never already mounted before the script is executed).

**Problem**

When executing this line in the PowerShell script from within an SSH session from `Computer A`...

```
New-PSDrive -Name $driveLetter -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $sharePath -Credential $cred
```

I *sometimes* get this familiar message

```
New-PSDrive : A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```

I'm aware that this is a classic [Double-Hop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.1) problem scenario and that there are ways around it. Security isn't too much of a concern as this is all on an isolated network. What's stumping me is the inconsistency.

**So far**

With some tinkering, I found that I could consistently create the `PSDrive` successfully after rebooting `Computer B` and *then* executing the PowerShell script. This was the case every single time and was the only way I could get the `PSDrive` to mount predictably. This isn't a major issue, but isn't exactly ideal for our automated process.

The `PSDrive` has successfully mounted without rebooting `Computer B` beforehand, but probably over 90% of the time it doesn't.

What can I do to make this step more consistent and reliable, preferrably without rebooting `Computer B` every time after the PowerShell script is run? Or is this simply a quirk of one of the components that I'm just going to have to work around?